# Error when extending from BrowserWindow electron class

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron

i used the https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue template to create a `vue` electron template. Beside main process `index.js` I created a file `MainWindow.js` which contains the following code:

```
import { BrowserWindow } from 'electron';

export class MainWindow extends BrowserWindow {
  constructor(url) {
    super({
      height: 500,
      width: 300,
      frame: false,
      resizable: false,
      show: false,
      webPreference: { backgroundThrottling: false }
    });
    console.log('constructor called.');

    // this.loadURL(url);
    this.on('blur', this.onBlur.bind(this));
  }

  onBlur() {
    this.hide();
  }
}
```

When I now try to create an instance of `MainWindow` I get the following error:

```
Requires constructor call

function createWindow() {
  /**
   * Initial window options
   */
  mainWindow = new MainWindow();

  mainWindow.loadURL(winURL);

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}
```

I don't get why this error occurs since I'm properly using `new`

Comment: Have you tried to use a unique name? Maybe it collides with a private property inside the `BrowserWindow` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to inherit from BrowserWindow. It is currently not supported.

Checkout:

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8898